# how to disable bluetooth after unsubscribing to nearby api with ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, google-nearby

I have read in other posts on SO that it's not possible to disable the bluetooth programatically.

Does this make sense? As i enable it programmatically when I subscribe to (google) nearby api.

Here is my code. Unsubscribing doesn't disable the BT.

Any other way to achieve that?

```
/// Stops publishing/subscribing.
public func unsubscribeNearbyApi() {
    subscription = nil
    //                    self.messageMgr?.removeObserver(<#T##observer: NSObject##NSObject#>, forKeyPath: <#T##String#>)
    //                    self.messageMgr?.removeObserver(<#T##observer: NSObject##NSObject#>, forKeyPath: <#T##String#>, context:<#T##UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>#>)
}

/// Starts scanning for nearby devices that are publishing
// their names.
func subscribeNearbyApi() {

    let params: GNSSubscriptionParams = GNSSubscriptionParams.init(
        messageNamespace: "inline-beacon",
        type: "line",
        strategy:
        GNSStrategy.init(paramsBlock: { (params: GNSStrategyParams!) -> Void in
            params.includeBLEBeacons = true;
        }))

    if (self.messageMgr == nil)
    {
        getPermissions()
    }
    if let messageMgr = self.messageMgr {
        subscription = messageMgr.subscriptionWithParams(params,
            messageFoundHandler:{[unowned self] (message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsubscribing in Google Nearby will not disable Bluetooth; it will simply stop doing any BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) operations.

And it's true that Apple provides no way to programmatically disable/enable BT on iOS; the idea is that the user should have control it exclusively.

Comment: though the BT is switch to "enable" when the scan starts? according to `Apple provides no way to programmatically disable/enable BT` it's no possible

Comment: It's not enabled automatically when an app tries to start BT operations.  The user has to turn it on.  The Nearby Messages library provides a callback to keep the app up to date with the BT power setting.  See the "Tracking user settings that affect Nearby" section on this page:  https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/pub-sub